# iOS 13 Dark mode: traitCollectionDidChange only called the first time

Tags: ios, swift, collections, traits

My app uses custom color themes but iOS13 users can opt into following dark mode.

I thought I could simply update my colors in the `ViewController's` `traitCollectionDidChange()` but for some reason, this function is only called the first time the user changes the interface style in the iOS settings.
While this may be sufficient for most users, ideally `traitCollectionDidChange()` should be called every time the user changes their iOS settings.

Just very basic:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
  super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
  print(#function)

  guard traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle != previousTraitCollection?.userInterfaceStyle else { return }

  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(Keys.Notifications.updateColorTheme), object: nil)
}
```

I launch my app, leave it, change appearance in the iOS settings: the next time I open the app (open, not launch), the above function is called and the app updates colors.
Now, when I repeat the same process, the function is not called anymore.

Comment: Somewhat unrelated but your code assumes that `traitCollectionDidChange` is only called when the light/dark mode changes. `traitCollectionDidChange` is called for many possible reasons. You should check if the light/dark mode changed so you only call your notification when appropriate.

Comment: @rmaddy, thank you for pointing that out. I've simplified the code for the example but indeed, it should be included. I have updated my post. Just for anyone reading this and wondering, this function will be called on device rotation as well, for instance.

Comment: @nontomatic Have you found any real resolution to why it's not called on dark mode change? I see the same - it's called on font size change or other things but not always light/dark.

Comment: I also had another dev hard code the app theme to Light in the Info.plist file. D'oh!

Comment: @Chirs Paveglio No, I did not. However, I managed to have my app respond properly to dark mode settings. It's been some time, but I think I updated the color theme by posting a notification in the appWillEnterForeground.

Answer (score 5):

I found that if I set UIViewController's `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` property, then the `traitCollectionDidChange` method not called, however when I don't set this `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` property, the `traitCollectionDidChange` is called.

maybe there have some internal method call judge in UIKit based on `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` property.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

The default value of `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` is `.unspecified` . If you want to be called it again, just revert it to `.unspecified` after setting to `.light` or `.dark'